# node-static cannot serve a folder above current folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-static

I don't know if this is a limitation to `node-static` or is it a bug in my code, but I can't seem to get it to serve files above or beyond the current directory. My current directory structure is this:

```
project
    public
        ...public stuff here...
    system
        core
           server.js
```

`server.js` lives in `core` directory, making the path to `public` as `../../public` - but this code won't run. It returns a 404.

```
staticServer = new (static.Server)('../../public');

webServer = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    staticServer.serve(request,response);
})

webServer.listen(appServerConfig.port, appServerConfig.address);
```

However, if I change the structure to make the public folder live beside `server.js` and change the code accordingly, it works:

```
project
    system
        core
           server.js
           public
               ...public stuff here...


staticServer = new (static.Server)('./public');

webServer = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    staticServer.serve(request,response);
})

webServer.listen(appServerConfig.port, appServerConfig.address);
```

Why is this so?

Comment: What does `console.log(path.resolve('../../public' || '.'))` give you?

Comment: @ebohlman it gives me the absolute location of the public folder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be aware that using relative paths will resolve those paths relative to the current working directory of the node.js process, that is, the directory you were in when you ran `node server.js`. So as coded, your could looks OK to me as long as you are in the `core` directory when you launch node. Are you sure you always launch node from the `core` directory?

If you want to be independent of the cwd (more robust IMHO), use `__dirname` to get the absolute directory path of the current file and then tack on your relative paths to that: `__dirname + '/../../public'`.

Beyond that, consider [fs.realpath](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/all.html#all_fs_realpath_path_cache_callback) to resolve those. I can't say whether node-static in particular has special code to prevent this, but most other modules I've seen such as connect's static middleware will happily serve any arbitrary directory without special restrictions.

Comment: solved. my `server.js` is run by another file outside the core directory, which is causing the issue.

Comment: Bingo man, didn't realise a `/` would help me so much knowing they are relative to when the file is called.